# Chrome Packaged App: communicate with parent window (chrome.app.window)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

i'm implementing the `chrome.app.window` api within my packaged app as following:

Parent code:

```
var win;
chrome.app.window.create('main.html', {id:'foo', alwaysOnTop: true}, function(_win){
    _win.contentWindow.test_close = function() {
        console.log('closing');
        _win.close();
    }
    win = _win;
});
```

now, after opening a window with that code, i can call `win.test_close()` from the parent window.

but how can i call a method defined in the parent page, from the child page?

(something like `parent.contentWindow.func_name()`)

is there any way for me to get the parent window reference ?

thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok well this is embarrassing, i solved it by typing:

```
this.opener.func_name()
```

in the child window.

hope it will help someone some day :-)